# Create Stages in TFS release manager dynamically

Tags: tfs

We have a release pipeline which runs many tests, now we want to run each test as a different stage of pipeline. Problem is there are different number of tests for each use case so can't fix the stages while designing the pipeline.

Is there a way by which I can create stages during runtime. (when a release has been created and it's running)

Comment: Thanks Patrick. We dropped the plan of having dynamic stages

Answer (score 1):

Actually, no, there is no such way to handle this situation. The stage could not be created during the running of Release.

Stages are the major divisions in your release pipeline: "run functional tests", "deploy to pre-production", and "deploy to production" are good examples of release stages.

A stage in a release pipeline consists of **jobs** and **tasks**.  To run each test as a different stage of pipeline is also not a recommend way.

Instead, you can use some filters and multiple test tasks to split cases. Please also take a look at this blog which may be useful:  [Staged execution of tests in Azure DevOps Pipelines](https://jessehouwing.net/staged-execution-of-tests-in-azure-devops-pipelines/)

Answer (score 1):

No, this cannot happen because a Release Pipelines are a "snapshot" of the pipeline and its tasks as they existed at that time.  That means any associated Task Groups that get modified after a Release Pipeline is initiated will not get changed in the created Release Pipeline because that Release Pipeline "snapshot" has already been created and is running.  This is actually a good thing since you don't want your pipeline to change when running and you are making changes.  So back to the problem.  There are some workarounds, but you aren't going to like them:

1. Use the REST API and a Release Pipeline JSON template to dynamically create a Release Pipeline on-the-fly (along with it's stages and associated tasks withing each stage).  This is a little complex, but it can be done.  You need to understand the relationships of elements within the json and minimal required json elements to get this working, which will be on a try-until-it-works basis.
2. Use Stage Pre-Condition checks, but they might not be mature enough to check some conditions that you are probably looking for.  Even Gate checks using Azure Function Apps might help here but it is either FAIL or PASS.  But still, take a look into Azure Function Apps that can extend the pre-condition checks you might need to run because I have no idea you are using as conditions.  I like Azure Function Apps!
3. I don't know how you are running your tests, but you can run PowerShell as tasks. So within a stage (before you run the test) you can run a PowerShell script to evaluate the condition use-case to run the test and set some Variable.  Then in the next step that will actually run the Test set Custom Conditions to run the Test Task and evaluate the Variable that you set in the previous PowerShell step to either run the Test Task or skip it.  The downside is that it will show the Stage as "GREEN" and not greyed out like it was skipped as if you had used Pre-Deployment Conditions.  You probably want to show in the Release Pipeline that the test was actually skipped and if it was passed or failed.
4. I'm sure I'm missing another option, but these are just off the top off my head.

Let me know what you come up with.

Comment: Thanks Antebios. We tried the rest api approach but went into many other issues while implementing it,so we dropped that idea. Now we have One stage as one environment and running the each test as a task group

Comment: Yeah, that is the best way.  I find it is easier to create a PowerShell script task and set variables there with `##vso[task.setvariable variable=VariableName]VariableValue` and then evaluate it in the next Task's "Custom Condition" with something like `and(succeeded(), eq(variables['VariableName'],'VariableValue'))` so that the task only execute if the previous tasks was Successful and if the VariableName meets a certain criteria.

Comment: See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions/ and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions/